# Multiple alteration spells?

Tags: ashes

Can a player attach multiple alteration spells to the same unit? If so, can a player attach multiple alteration spells of the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, multiple alteration spells may be attached to the same unit.**

From the top of page 3 in the [Plaid Hat Games FAQ about Ashes](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/ashes/faq.pdf):

> **Q:** Can a unit have multiple alteration spells attached to it? Can they be the same spell?
>
> **A:** Yes to both. You may have multiple alteration spells attached to a unit, and you may have multiple copies of a single alteration spell attached to a unit.